# Can pip be used with a custom metapath finder?

Tags: python, pip

In my environment, I need to manually install python packages in a non-standard location, and I need to archive the source tarballs of the packages I install.  I'm using python 3.11.  I install packages by downloading tarballs and running:

`python3 -m pip install --prefix=xxx --no-deps --no-index --ignore-installed .`

where `xxx` is the location where I'm installing.  I realize that this is tedious and in many cases it would be unnecessary, but in this particular environment, it's what I'm stuck with.

I've written a metapath finder that is able to locate packages where I have them installed (by implementing `find_spec()`), and it is able to find package metadata (by implementing `find_distributions()`).  Both work fine.  I can import modules I've installed, and I can use `pip3 list` to get a list of the available packages.

The way I load my metapath finder is through `usercustomize.py`, so the finder is in place before any other module begins and this whole process is transparent to users.

Everything works, except that when I try to install a package which requires another (via `requires` in the `build_system` section of `pyproject.toml`), required packages are not found, even if they are installed and visible via `pip3 list`.

My question is what does `pip3 install` do that `pip3 list` doesn't do in terms of locating dependent packages?

**Edit**

If I instrument my metapth finder's `find_distributions()` to print the distributions it finds, I see that it's being called from ```pip install`` and it returns all of the distributions.  I can print the distribution version numbers, and they are correct, so I know the metadata has been parsed correctly.

Yet, `pip install` complains with:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flit_core>=3.4 (from versions: none)
```

Looking through pip's internals, it looks like the `versions: none` is coming from an exploration of the installable packages.  I don't have any installable packages because I'm using `--no-index`.  But why do we need the installable packages if what it's looking for is already installed?

**Edit 2**

To reproduce the error:

1. Start with a new installation of python 3.11.2, and make sure that's the python3/pip3 in the path.
2. Get `pip` upgraded and `wheel` installed:

   ```
   pip3 install wheel
   pip3 install --upgrade pip
   ```
3. Download `flit_core-3.8.0.tar.gz` and `build-0.10.0.tar.gz` from pypi.
4. Install flit_core in a non-standard place:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/nonstandard
   tar zxvf flit_core-3.8.0.tar.gz
   cd flit_core-3.8.0
   python3 -m pip install --prefix=/tmp/nonstandard --no-deps --no-index --ignore-installed .
   ```
5. Although the installation works, python doesn't know to look in /tmp/nonstandard, so fix that by putting the following in `usercustomize.py`.

   ```py
   import sys
   import os
   import importlib.abc
   import importlib.metadata
   import importlib.util


   MyPackages = {
       'flit_core' : 
       {
       'location':'/tmp/nonstandard/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flit_core',
       'metadata':'/tmp/nonstandard/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flit_core-3.8.0.dist-info',
       },
   }


   class MyMetaPathFinder(importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder):

       def find_spec(self, module_name, path, target=None):
           if module_name in sys.modules:
               return sys.modules[module_name].__spec__

           if module_name in MyPackages:
               module_dir = MyPackages[module_name]['location']
               file = os.path.join(module_dir, '__init__.py')
               spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file,
                                                             submodule_search_locations=[])

               # Hack so if there are any subsequent submodule imports, they will
               # be found through the path
               if module_dir in sys.path:
                   sys.path.remove(module_dir)
               sys.path.insert(0, module_dir)

               return spec
           else:
               return None


       def find_distributions(self, context=importlib.metadata.DistributionFinder.Context()):
           if context.name is None:
               distributions = [ importlib.metadata.PathDistribution.at(MyPackages[p]['metadata']) for p in MyPackages ]
           else:
               try:
                   distributions = [ importlib.metadata.PathDistribution.at(MyPackages[context.name]['metadata'])]
               except KeyError:
                   distributions = []

           return distributions

   sys.meta_path.insert(2, MyMetaPathFinder())
   ```

With that in place, we can now import `flit_core`, and it will show up in `pip3 list`.

6. Now try to install `build-0.10.0`, which has:

   ```
   [build-system]
   requires = ["flit-core >= 3.4"]
   ```

in its `pyproject.toml`.

```
tar zxvf build-0.10.0.tar.gz
cd build-0.10.0/
python3 -m pip install --prefix=/tmp/nonstandard --no-deps --no-index --ignore-installed .
```

The installation fails with:

```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flit-core>=3.4 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for flit-core>=3.4
```

even though I can tell by instrumenting `find_distributions()`, that it is being called and is returning `flit_core`.

Comment: Debugging an issue like this is going to require a [mre] - in this case, that is going to involve starting *completely* from scratch, and explaining exactly what Python installations need to be present, what you've written in `usercustomize.py`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the original error (regarding flit-core) as I am in a similar situation. From another forum, I happened upon: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-build-isolation.

I was attempting to unpack wheel.tar.gz using pip and was running into the flit-core error (despite having just pip'd that). The pip list reports that it can, in fact, see the version 3.8.

However, once I added no-build-isolation to the pip line, PIP proceeded to install wheel.